# Multithreading with gpu in OpenCV

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, gpu

I wrote a program that computes the optical flow using **gpu::BroxOpticalFlow** on a set of images. The code compiles and runs fine in case of single thread execution.

Since I'm trying to find the best parameter configuration for the optical flow computation, I need to run the code several time on the same set of images. Therefore, to speed up the process, I decided to use multithreading to run multiple optical flow computations with different parameters in parallel. To do so, I simply created a thread for each optical flow process, with completely different objects and variables.

When I run the code, I occasionally get these runtime errors from the gpu function that computes the optical flow:

```
OpenCV Error: Gpu API call (NCV Assertion Failed: cudaError_t=77, file=/home/user/opencv-2.4.10/modules/gpu/src/nvidia/NCVBroxOpticalFlow.cu, line=1018
) in outputHandler, file /home/user/opencv-2.4.10/modules/gpu/src/optical_flow.cpp, line 72
OpenCV Error: Gpu API call (NCV Assertion Failed: cudaError_t=77, file=/home/user/opencv-2.4.10/modules/gpu/src/nvidia/NCVBroxOpticalFlow.cu, line=1018
) in outputHandler, file /home/user/opencv-2.4.10/modules/gpu/src/optical_flow.cpp, line 72
OpenCV Error: Gpu API call (NCV Assertion Failed: cudaError_t=77, file=/home/user/opencv-2.4.10/modules/gpu/src/nvidia/NCVBroxOpticalFlow.cu, line=1018
) in outputHandler, file /home/user/opencv-2.4.10/modules/gpu/src/optical_flow.cpp, line 72
OpenCV Error: Gpu API call (an illegal memory access was encountered) in copy, file /home/user/opencv-2.4.10/modules/dynamicuda/include/opencv2/dynamicuda/dynamicuda.hpp, line 877
```

Apparently a different thread accessed to a memory locations reserved to another thread.
However, according to what I've understood from the OpenCV and CUDA documentations, every time a CPU thread uses a GPU function a new context is created with dedicated resources and it is not accessible by other thread.

Did I misunderstand how multithreading works with GPU functions? Is there a way to avoid illegal memory access by other threads?

Comment: Did you find solution to this problem. I am facing the same crash in multi-threaded setup as reported by you.

Comment: Any word on this. I am also getting the same.

Comment: Any update ? I got this with opencv-4.0.0 and cuda 9.2, despite the multiple mutexes for thread safe read/write. It looks like between threads of 1 process it's fine, but when I have multiple processes (eg with unit tests), I got the errors.

Comment: Elements of answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990228/opencv-gpu-farneback-optical-flow-badly-works-in-multi-threading?rq=1