# OpenCV GPU Farneback Optical Flow badly works in multi-threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, gpu, opticalflow

My application uses the Opencv gpu class `gpu::FarnebackOpticalFlow` to compute the optical flow between a pair of consecutive frames of an input video. In order to speed-up the process, I exploited the TBB support of OpenCV to run the method in multi-threading. However, the multi-threading performance does not behave like the single-threaded one. Just to give you an idea of the different behaviour, here are two snapshots, respectively of the single threaded and the multi threaded implementation.

[image: single threaded optical flow]
[image: multi threaded optical flow]

The multi-threaded implementation assumes to split the image in 8 different stripes (the number of cores on my pc), and the gpu method for the Farneback implementation of the optical flow is applied on each of them. Here are the corresponding code lines for both methods:

**Single-threaded implementation**

```
/* main.cpp */
//prevImg and img are the input Mat images extracted from the input video
...
GpuMat gpuImg8U(img);
GpuMat gpuPrevImg8U(prevImg);   
GpuMat u_flow, v_flow;
gpu::FarnebackOpticalFlow farneback_flow;
farneback_flow.numLevels = maxLayer;
farneback_flow.pyrScale = 0.5;
farneback_flow.winSize = windows_size;
farneback_flow.numIters = of_iterations;
farneback_flow(gpuPrevImg8U,gpuImg8U,u_flow,v_flow);
getFlowField(Mat(u_flow),Mat(v_flow),optical_flow);

...
}

void getFlowField(const Mat& u, const Mat& v, Mat& flowField){    
    for (int i = 0; i < flowField.rows; ++i){
        const float* ptr_u = u.ptr<float>(i);
        const float* ptr_v = v.ptr<float>(i);
        Point2f* row = flowField.ptr<Point2f>(i);

        for (int j = 0; j < flowField.cols; ++j){
            row[j].y = ptr_v[j];
            row[j].x = ptr_u[j];
        }
    }
}
```

**Multi-threaded implementation**

```
/* parallel.h */
class ParallelOpticalFlow : public cv::ParallelLoopBody {

    private:
        int coreNum;
        cv::gpu::GpuMat img, img2;
        cv::gpu::FarnebackOpticalFlow& farneback_flow;
        const cv::gpu::GpuMat u_flow, v_flow;
        cv::Mat& optical_flow;

    public:
        ParallelOpticalFlow(int cores, cv::gpu::FarnebackOpticalFlow& flowHandler, cv::gpu::GpuMat img_, cv::gpu::GpuMat img2_, const cv::gpu::GpuMat u, const cv::gpu::GpuMat v, cv::Mat& of)
                    : coreNum(cores), farneback_flow(flowHandler), img(img_), img2(img2_), u_flow(u), v_flow(v), optical_flow(of){}

        virtual void operator()(const cv::Range& range) const;

};


/* parallel.cpp*/
void ParallelOpticalFlow::operator()(const cv::Range& range) const {

    for (int k = range.start ; k < range.end ; k ++){

        cv::gpu::GpuMat img_rect(img,cv::Rect(0,img.rows/coreNum*k,img.cols,img.rows/coreNum));
        cv::gpu::GpuMat img2_rect(img2,cv::Rect(0,img2.rows/coreNum*k,img2.cols,img2.rows/coreNum));
        cv::gpu::GpuMat u_rect(u_flow,cv::Rect(0,u_flow.rows/coreNum*k,u_flow.cols,u_flow.rows/coreNum));
        cv::gpu::GpuMat v_rect(v_flow,cv::Rect(0,v_flow.rows/coreNum*k,v_flow.cols,v_flow.rows/coreNum));
        cv::Mat of_rect(optical_flow,cv::Rect(0,optical_flow.rows/coreNum*k,optical_flow.cols,optical_flow.rows/coreNum));

        farneback_flow(img_rect,img2_rect,u_rect,v_rect);
        getFlowField(Mat(u_rect),Mat(v_rect),of_rect);
    }
}

/* main.cpp */

    parallel_for_(Range(0,cores_num),ParallelOpticalFlow(cores_num,farneback_flow,gpuPrevImg8U,gpuImg8U,u_flow,v_flow,optical_flow));
```

The codes look like equivalent in the two cases. Can anyone explain me why there are these different behaviours? Or if there are some mistakes in my code?
Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: what are your values for img/img2/u_flow/v_flow/optical_flow.rows, img/img2/u_flow/v_flow/optical_flow.cols, coreNum, k (range)? Is there a reason why you didn't use the same images up there?

Comment: [rows x cols] = [240x320], coreNum = 8, k is the iterator indexing each of the cores. I use the same images in both methods, with the difference that each image and matrix is splitted in 8 stripes in multi-threading, to make the optical flow to work in a parallel way

Comment: did you test to split the image in for example  2 parts only? probably flow cant be detected correctly over your subimage borders.

Comment: Yes I tried, and the result is still worse.

Comment: it probably works if you just use a single subimage/slice (created the same way)? It probably is a data race as @jet47 says. But I don't see where splitting the GPU calls is of help anyways. Looks like you are trying to use multiple CPUs waiting for the GPU-bottleneck. So even if it worked you would reduce the flow quality (no inter-slice flow detected) without a speedup (that isn't from the reduced quality).

Comment: Mmm you're right, I didn't think about that. I discarded this option of using the gpu-based method, I replaced it with the cpu-based one, in multi-threading. The resulting flow is better than in the gpu case, but it is quite noisy and unstable at the bottom of each slice/subimage. Actually this is the same effect that I observe with a single image in the single-threaded implementation, but here it is replicated for each subimage. Should I conclude that it is problem of the Farneback function?

Comment: is it noisy just at the bottom, or at the whole border (top and bottom) of each slice? If you compute the flow in two images you can only compute it correctly in overlapping scenery regions (meant pixel regions that can be found in both images). same holds for subimages, so if you try to find the pixel correspondences in a slice it won't take into account the neighboring slices automatically (since you only provided one slice). Hard to explain...

Comment: Yes, with a more accurate observation it appears to be noisy on all the borders. So, if I got what you mean, this happens because the algorithm cannot find a correspondence in the second image, for the border pixels of the first image? Is it correct?

Comment: That would be the most certain assumption. Could be possible that openCV drops the border completely, but then I would assume that no single flow is detected there. To be completely sure you would have to look at the code or try some experiments by preparing special images (for example turning the camera slightly to the right should give wrong/no flow in the left image region while right image regions can theoretically all be computed, etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GPU module is not thread-safe. It uses some global variables, like `__constant__` memory and texture reference API, which can lead to data race if used in multi-threaded environment.

Comment: I see. Well, I will completely discard this option.
However, I tried to replace the gpu-based method with the cpu-based equivalent function. I observe a kind of noise and unstability at the bottom of each slice of the image, a similar effect to the single-threaded case. Do you think it could depend on how the Farneback function works on the input image?

Comment: Is it safe to call gpu function with different gpu::Stream-s from different host threads?  Is it safe to call from separate host threads different gpu functions?

Comment: First answer is no. Second - yes, with exceptions. Some functions uses another, for example ORB internally uses FAST, so it is not safe to use ORB and FAST simultaneously.

Comment: @jet47 GPU module is not safe, but If I use multiple instances (multiple processes), can it work ? It seems to me that it does not.